# Use SharePoint:ProjectProperty in C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint

Excuse me if this is something simple or there's a better way to do this. What I want to do is get my subsite's URL, and use it in my master page in some C#. I know that I can use `<SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property="Url" runat="server"/>` in the master page to grab the URL property, but I want to be able to use it in a C# block. My end goal is to be able to include content from a file and output it through the master page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the [`Url`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.url.aspx) value from `SPSite`

Specifically, you can get the value from the current site:

```
SPContext.Current.Site.Url
```

> The Url property contains a string such as `http://Host_Name:80/sites/Site_Name`. Note that the URL does not end with a slash ("/").